# Force existing rows to be unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

Is there a way to force existing rows to be unique on a column before adding a unique constraint? I am adding this constraint to my db:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customfields_name_org_id_key 
ON CustomFields(name, org_id) 
WHERE deleted IS false;
```

But would like to first find all cases where this constraint wouldn't be met, and add 1 to the name of one of the rows (recursively adding more 1s if more than two columns that collide). Is there a way to do this in POstgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You would just check:

```
select name, org_id, count(*)
from customfields
where not deleted
group by name, org_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I change the names of these rows as I described, to make them unique. Sorry for the basic question, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @DazedAndConfused . . . Do you have a primary key on the table?